# Stunnel 5.x on Centos 6.5

Tags: centos, openssl, ssl, rpmbuild, stunnel

Im looking for an stunnel 5.x RPM for Centos 6.5 so I can get TLS1.2 support. Ive looked everywhere, but cannot find one. Ive tried downloading and compiling, as per another question on here (title: Stunnel 5.4 on Centos ), and followed all the instructions, but am running into compile errors.

The command is: `rpmbuild -ta stunnel-5.46.tar.gz`

Here is an example.

```
client.c:147: warning: expected [error|warning|ignored] after '#pragma GCC diagnostic'
client.c:180: warning: expected [error|warning|ignored] after '#pragma GCC diagnostic'
client.c:203: warning: expected [error|warning|ignored] after '#pragma GCC diagnostic'

/root/rpmbuild/BUILD/stunnel-5.46/src/client.c:487: undefined reference to `OpenSSL_version_num'
/root/rpmbuild/BUILD/stunnel-5.46/src/client.c:487: undefined reference to `OpenSSL_version_num'
/root/rpmbuild/BUILD/stunnel-5.46/src/client.c:488: undefined reference to `OpenSSL_version_num'

/root/rpmbuild/BUILD/stunnel-5.46/src/stunnel.c:897: undefined reference to `OpenSSL_version'
/root/rpmbuild/BUILD/stunnel-5.46/src/stunnel.c:899: undefined reference to `OpenSSL_version'
/root/rpmbuild/BUILD/stunnel-5.46/src/stunnel.c:900: undefined reference to `OpenSSL_version_num'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [stunnel] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/rpmbuild/BUILD/stunnel-5.46/src'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/rpmbuild/BUILD/stunnel-5.46/src'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.mbHOf4 (%build)
```

If anyone can help, Id be grateful.

regards
Richard

Answer (score 0):

> CentOS 6.9 - x86_64 .... stunnel-5.46

Setup the "rpmbuild environment" $HOME/rpms/ https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/need-rpm-package-for-php-version-5-2-7-and-up-on-redhat-5-1-a-766486/#13

`$ rpm -i http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/development/rawhide/Everything/source/tree/Packages/s/stunnel-5.46-1.fc29.src.rpm`

```
$ cd rpms/SPECS/                      // Edit stunnel.spec to :

: 37 : # BuildRequires: systemd       // comment out "BuildRequires: systemd"
: 69 : make                           // edit to "no-pie" ( to 'make' only )

$ rpmbuild -bb stunnel.spec
.
Wrote: /home/knudfl/rpms/RPMS/x86_64/stunnel-5.46-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /home/knudfl/rpms/RPMS/x86_64/stunnel-debuginfo-5.46-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

**stunnel_make.log.txt** https://www.dropbox.com/s/idn5i7mrn16feor/stunnel_make.log.txt?dl=0

Package `stunnel-5.46-1.el6.x86_64.rpm` https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Sd7TdW9GWJppN_jqsmVE9U68gBCxn3sr/view?usp=sharing

`# yum install Downloads/stunnel-5.46-1.el6.x86_64.rpm`

---

My install test ...

```
# yum install /home/knudfl/rpms/RPMS/x86_64/stunnel-5.46-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
.
.
Running Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
  Updating   : stunnel-5.46-1.el6.x86_64
/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.82cIfj: line 2: fg: no job control
warning: %post(stunnel-5.46-1.el6.x86_64) scriptlet failed, exit status 1
Non-fatal POSTIN scriptlet failure in rpm package stunnel-5.46-1.el6.x86_64
  Cleanup    : stunnel-4.56-4.el6.x86_64
  Verifying  : stunnel-5.46-1.el6.x86_64
  Verifying  : stunnel-4.56-4.el6.x86_64
```

The "Non-fatal POSTIN scriptlet failure" is about `%systemd_post stunnel.service` → No systemd in CentOS 6. ... **Note**: Information like "line 2: fg: no job control" and warnings are **not** errors. Just information.

Installing the default `stunnel-4.29` (again) : https://www.dropbox.com/s/tvhyt44br567jkr/stunnel_install.txt?dl=0

Comment: »» undefined reference to `OpenSSL_version_num` «« : Looks like you are using a corrupt or incomplete OpenSSL ? ... Is your `openssl-devel` updated to the latest update ? Or are you using a home made OpenSSL ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response.. Ive followed all the instructions, and get as far as compiling. However, Im getting similar erros as before..  Ive copied the output into a log file..  https://www.dropbox.com/s/ym77m7by6p5cziv/stunnel_build.log?dl=0

Comment: ok. thx.  How do I check that?  I did an openSSL update..  Ill do a clean reinstall. Which version should I  be using? Ive installed openssl-1.0.1e-57.0.1.el6.x86_64

Comment: »» Which version should I be using «« : There is only one version : `# yum install openssl-devel` will do the update.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Ive removed and reinstalled openssl and openssl-devel using yum remove ...    then reinstalled, but Im still getting the same set of errors:
Packages are: openssl-1.0.1e-57.0.1.el6.x86_64   and 
openssl-devel-1.0.1e-57.0.1.el6.x86_64

Comment: Maybe installing `stunnel-5.46-1.el6.x86_64.rpm` will discover your "OS issues" ? .... See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks Knud. Does it atcually install correctly on your system? Im getting an error. (Ive now tried on another centos 6 machine where I can compile without any errors:  When I install I get:  f
[root@uvhqoracle01 root]# rpm -ivh stunnel-5.46-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:stunnel                ########################################### [100%]
/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.8hlVBf: line 2: fg: no job control
warning: %post(stunnel-5.46-1.el6.x86_64) scriptlet failed, exit status 1

Comment: then I get an error when trying to either remove or install it..                       [root@uvhqoracle01 root]# rpm -e stunnel
/var/tmp/rpm-tmp.lZWyb9: line 1: fg: no job control
error: %preun(stunnel-5.46-1.el6.x86_64) scriptlet failed, exit status 1

Comment: Ive tried both rpm and yum, with similar errors..

Comment: Package install : Please use `# yum install Downloads/stunnel-5.46-1.el6.x86_64.rpm` → and yum will install with option `rpm -Uvh`. I.e. do not use `-ivh`. Removing a package : `# yum remove stunnel`. ... My install test : See the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

TLS v1.2 is already supported in stunnel 4.56 available with rhel/centos 6.x.

However, 6.5 is quite an old release, so you should move to 6.9 (or soon 6.10) to have latest openssl package.